# How to select all cells <th> and <td> alike

Tags: css, html-parsing, nokogiri

Pardon if this is very basic.  I have been trying to traverse each cell *including header cells* in an array of rows.  Is there an OR operator I can use in the Nokogiri CSS selector?

```
thang= Nokogiri::HTML(IO.read "|cat page.html").css('table[@id="costbasisTable"] tr')
```

Correctly fetches all rows including a header row (which repeats on subsequent pages):

```
thang[0].inner_html
=> <th class="tLeft"></th><th>cellA2</th><th>cellA3data</th>

thang[1].inner_html
=> <td>cellB1</td><td>cellB2</td><td>cellB3data</td>
```

The trouble is with the following, which may return blank if that row contains only **th**'s not **td**'s:

```
N=0
thang[N].css("td").map{|c| c.text.strip.gsub(/\t.*/,"").delete ",".tr("&/|:;\n","_")}.to_a
```

What parameter to **.css(...)** will mean "match any `<td>` OR `<th>` cell"?

Is this possible/better done with **.xpath()** instead for these Nokogiri XML Elements?

Comment: I'm not sure what Nokogiri is, but the following CSS selector would work: `table tr > *`

Comment: I can't get `thang[0].css("table tr > *")` to catch any cells. Tried `thang[1]`, and varied the CSS selector a bit too

Comment: `.css('td, th')` or `.xpath('./td|./th')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use either of the following:

```
# thang[n] is a Nokogiri <tr> node
cells = thang[n].css('th,td')
cells = thang[n].xpath('./th | ./td')
```

Note that the CSS version will match any embedded tables (if you had such a horror) while the XPath version will only match direct children of the row.

Comment: Thanks. `cells = thang[n].css('*')` also matched header and non-header cells I needed (not sure what else * would include here)

Comment: The problem with `cells = thang[n].css('th,td')` is that the order is lost. `cells` will contain all `th`s first, then all `td`s. So `<table><th></th><td></td><th></th><td></td></table>` gives `['th','th','td','td']`. I'm looking to get all `th`s and `td`s, but preserving their order. :-(

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch `doc.xpath('//th | //td')` does preserve their order, as does `doc.xpath('//*[name()="th" or name()="td"]')`.